# Unable to re-arrange icons in Dock launcher by drag-and-drop

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, favorites

Using Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME 3.28.2 and with the"Favourites" Dock on the default left side of the screen. Whenever an icon is clicked, it "pops" off the Launcher as expected but cannot be moved to a new location. The popped icon sort of "hangs" in mid-air and when you release the mouse it goes back to its original position. The other icons do not move as expected when the "popped" icon is moved over them.

It was possible to configure Dock icons from the bash terminal as follows:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps
```

This returns

```
['app1.desktop', 'app2.desktop', 'app3.desktop']
```

Now the order of `app1` and `app2` can be switched with the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps "['app2.desktop', 'app1.desktop', 'app3.desktop']"
```

Why is drag-and-drop not working?

Comment: In my case it's working but it's very slow. It showing the rearranged dock icons after a minute when I'm rearranging icons using drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

In my case running a web app made with `nativefier`, the issue was that the value of `StartupWMClass` in the `.desktop` file must match the name of the program, including the hex which is generated the first time the app runs.

Hover over the app in the dock to see the name of the app and make sure `StartupWMClass` matches that.

Example `.desktop` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Outlook Mail
GenericName=Outlook Mail
X-GNOME-FullName=Outlook Mail
Comment=Outlook Mail created by nativefier
Categories=Email;Communication;
Exec=/home/afr/nativefier/outlook-mail-linux-x64/outlook-mail %F
TryExec=/home/afr/nativefier/outlook-mail-linux-x64/outlook-mail
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/html;
StartupNotify=true
Icon=/home/afr/nativefier/outlook-mail-linux-x64/resources/app/icon.png
StartupWMClass=outlook-mail-nativefier-f3f410
```

The value of the last line is the one that must match the name of the app.