# Dash to dock favorite icons stopped re-arranging with drag and drop

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, dash-to-dock

Whenever I use the cursor to drag and change the position of an icon in the dock it just hangs for a moment and goes back to it's original place.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Same question: https://askubuntu.com/q/1173460/480481 (unanswered).

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbjr5.gif

Comment: @PRATAP It looks like it's "Dash to Dock" in your screen capture. Even though OP mentioned Dash to Dock, I believe they're actually using the default "Ubuntu Dock" (a fork of Dash to Dock). It seems the same cannot be done with the default Ubuntu Dock (I couldn't do it either).